# How to use getInstance() with 2 parameters

Tags: apex, method, global-variables, instance

I have a class with a method from which I want to make an instance but on saving the instance method I get the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getInstance() from
>   the type FahCreator

I am expecting to do :

```
FAHCreator.getInstance().generateAndInsertFARecords(scope, 'string');
```

Apex

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<sObject> scope){
    FAHCreator.getInstance().generateAndInsertFARecords(scope);
}



public map<id,string> generateAndInsertFARecords(List<sObject> records, string source){
    system.debug('FAHCreator: generateAndInsertFARecords() '+ source + ' ' + string.valueOf(records.size()));
    map<id,string> result = new map<id,string>();
 ..
```

Comment: What is the definition of the class `FAHCreator`? You have to have a static method that takes those parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAHCreator apparently doesn't have a getInstance() method. You should add it to that class:

```
public class FAHCreator {
  static final FAHCreator instance = new FAHCreator();
  public static FAHCreator getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }
  // Other code
}
```

From there, you still need to make sure that you're using two paramters on `generateAndInsertFARecords` (your Apex example shows only one parameter).